# Triggers in mysql after insert

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am new to programing and need a little help in triggers. I want to create a trigger when a data is entered in 'Affiliate_Detail' table to update another column in same table which is the concatenation of characters "AF" and a field affiliateNumber. affiliateNumber is an auto increment, primary column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAffiliateId 
AFTER  INSERT
ON Affiliate_Detail
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Affiliate_Detail 
    SET affiliateId = CONCAT("AF", new.affiliateNumber);
END
```

Answer (score 0):

SolarFlare pointed out that the before insert recommendation below wouldn't work out in the case of auto inc primary keys because the value isn't known in a before insert, and you cannot update the same table in an after insert.

Because your requirement is relatively simple, you're just concatting a string and a number, I recommend you use a generated column for this

```
ALTER TABLE x
ADD COLUMN affiliateID VARCHAR(100)
GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('AF',new.affiliateNumber));
```

More info:

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-generated-columns/

---

Or even, don't bake this into your db - do it in the front end by tarting a transaction, inserting the record then Updating using the last_insert_id

---

For situations where it's other than an auto column:

Quote [the fine manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html):

> In a BEFORE trigger, you can also change its value with SET NEW. col_name = value if you have the UPDATE privilege for it. This means you can use a trigger to modify the values to be inserted into a new row or used to update a row.

Change your trigger to a BEFORE INSERT (and you'll probably also have to make it FOR EACH ROW) and write the new value directly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ... BEFORE INSERT ...
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.affiliateId=CONCAT('AF',new.affiliateNumber);
END
```

This isn't a set as in an update statement. This is set as in setting a variable in a typical programming language, like eg JavaScript `var x = "AF" + y;`

The docs I linked at the top have a boatload of examples

Side note, standard SQL uses apostrophe/single quote to denote strings and speech marks/double quotes to denote identifiers. While MySQL allows double quotes to denote strings, with database work it's often good to keep to standard so that you have fewer things to trip you up when you start working with another db

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER updateAffiliateId 
    BEFORE  INSERT
    on Affiliate_Detail
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET NEW.affiliateId=CONCAT('AF',NEW.affiliateNumber);
    END  //STILL SHOWS SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: @Root "shows an error" is less helpful than quoting the actual error.

Comment: @CaiusJard Although it solves the update-error, unfortunately, the autoincrement value is not yet usable in a before-insert-trigger (it is always 0).

Comment: @root Imagine you're working on the company helpdesk and a user rings up and says "something's not working" - what would you say? And then there would be some long back and forth conversation (where you eventually determine the power is out :) ) - it takes a really long time to have that back and forth conversation over stackoverflow. You should always provide all relevant details up front, to the level you'd want someone to give you if you were working helpdesk -steps to cause the problem, exactly what you see, what stage of the process you are at now, things tried, end goal you want to reach

Comment: Sorry , my bad. New to this world. I hope this helps [https://imgur.com/a/LwjLmB9]